# How to use Database login and Azure AD Authentication both in a react app at same time?

Tags: reactjs, database, authentication, react-router, azure-active-directory

I have created a react app in which I have a login page as the first page and there are two ways to login into it, first one is using Azure AD and second is database login.
I have implemented the Azure ad login part with the help of protected routes and all the stuff.

Now in the same app I want to implement the Database Login but I'm unable to do so.
So how it can be done. If anyone can help me in this?

App.tsx code:-

```
import './css/App.css';
import { AuthenticatedTemplate, UnauthenticatedTemplate } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { Login } from './auth/Login';
import Routers from './components/Router/Routers';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Routers />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.tsx code:-

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { msalConfig } from "./auth/authConfig";

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container!);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <App />
    </MsalProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

module.hot?.accept();
```

Auth.tsx code:-

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    AuthenticatedTemplate,
    UnauthenticatedTemplate,
} from "@azure/msal-react";
import { useIsAuthenticated } from "@azure/msal-react";

export const PrivateRoutes = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();

    return isAuthenticated
        ? (
            <AuthenticatedTemplate>
                <Outlet />
            </AuthenticatedTemplate>
        )
        : <Navigate to="/Login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
}

export const AnonymousRoutes = () => {

    const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();

    return isAuthenticated
        ? <Navigate to="/Home" replace /> 
        : (
            <UnauthenticatedTemplate>
                <Outlet />
            </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
        );
}
```

Router.tsx code:-

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../pages/Home";
import About from "../pages/About";
import Contact from "../pages/Contact";
import { Login } from "./pages/Login";
import { AnonymousRoutes, PrivateRoutes } from '../components/auth';

function Routers() {
  return (
    <div className="Routers">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} /> 
            <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/Contact" element={<Contact />} />
          </Route>
          <Route element={<AnonymousRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
        <Outlet />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So now with this code I want to implement database login also. Please suggest the possible way.

Comment: Once Check Active Directory at server level Azure Active Directory authentication only disabled or not.

Comment: @Bhavani Where can I check it? Not getting it's path.

Comment: Do you connect to azure SQL server for login using Active directory?

Comment: @Bhavani No I have simply registered my app there and with the help of clientId, redirectUri and authority I have established the connection with Azure AD

Comment: Are you trying to use two *different* authentication schemes in the same app? What database are you needing to log into?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese , Yes I am trying to use two different authentication schemes in the same app. And for database I am using my local DB which is "SQL SERVER 2014 MANAGEMENT STUDIO". My code flow is when I try to login using database the request is hitting at api endpoint with the help of axios and if the login id and password is correct the user will logged into the application but due to this private and anonymous route I am unable to do it.